# How do I find which viewController has pushed?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, runtime-error, pushviewcontroller

I have simple navigation code that transition from one `viewController` to the next.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"myStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myVC"];

UINavigationController *myNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];

[myNavigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
```

With this I get the error message:

> ...is pushing the same view controller instance ... more than once which is not supported and is most likely an error in the application

Now, I understand that somewhere in the app, the same `viewController` has (or can?) been pushed, and that code line needs to be removed or otherwise dealt with. Thing is, I'm working in a huge project and have no idea where that code line might be.

So, question is, how do I deal with this? Can I `pop` the `pushed` `viewController` programmatically before `pushing` the "correct" `viewController`? Or is there some way to locate the `push` that is causing the problem? Or can I solve it Ibn some other way?

Answer (score 0):

The navigation view controller is a stack of VC's.  If you walk the stack you can see what type of object it is.  You can then do a simple string compare of class type names.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I "walk the stack"? Could you be a bit more precise on what you mean?

Comment: viewcontroller.view.subview.subview.subview....

Comment: something like this:  let vcArray = self.navigationVC.viewArray;